# How do I preview emails in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

This might be a dumb question but when I'm putting together an HTML email in Rails, is there a particularly easy built-in way to preview the template it in the browser or do I need to write some sort of custom controller that pulls it in as its view?

Comment: Apparently there are no dumb questions :D

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Action Mailer now has a built in way of [previewing emails in **Rails 4.1**](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/4_1_release_notes.md#action-mailer-previews). For example, check this out:

```
# located in test/mailers/previews/notifier_mailer_preview.rb

class NotifierPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  # Accessible from http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/notifier/welcome
  def welcome
    Notifier.welcome(User.first)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello, in production environment send error with route when i try open url `ERROR ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET]`

In test environment i don't have problem.

Comment: @andres Pretty sure that's by design--you don't want users to preview your mail on production servers, it's meant only for local development.

Comment: @mpowered And what if I DO want users to be able to preview/modify mails they are about to send ? (Ex : a manager refuses a user application, and an email is sent to warn the applicant)

Comment: @CyrilDD You'd have to build something like that yourself, I don't think this would be the tool for that job.

Comment: The preview is available in http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/notifier/welcome, and a list of them in http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers.

Comment: If you're using Rspec, your previews go in `spec/mailers/previews`

Comment: Is `User.first` using test users from the `users.yml` fixture file or does `User.first` expect real users in the database? I'm getting a `first_name` for nil class error. I suspect we need to generate a real user...

Answer (score 75):

Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165189/254046) is a good start, but if your email templates contain any dynamic data, it won't work. E.g. suppose your email is an order receipt and within it you print out `@order.total_price` - using the previous method the `@order` variable will be nil.

Here's a little recipe I use:

First, since this email preview functionality is definitely for internal use only, I set up some generic routes in the admin namespace:

```
#routes.rb

MySite::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    match 'mailer(/:action(/:id(.:format)))' => 'mailer#:action'
  end
end
```

Next, I create the controller.  In this controller, I create one method per email template.  Since most emails contain dynamic data, we need to populate whatever member variables the template expects.

This could be done with fixtures, but I typically prefer to just grab some pseudo-random real data.  Remember - this is NOT a unit test - this is purely a development aid.  It doesn't need to produce the same result every single time - in fact - it's probably better if it doesn't!

```
#app/controllers/admin/mailer_controller.rb
class Admin::MailerController < Admin::ApplicationController

  def preview_welcome()
    @user = User.last
    render :file => 'mailer/welcome.html.erb', :layout => 'mailer'
  end

end
```

Note that when we render the template, we use `layout=>:mailer`.  This embeds the body of your email inside the HTML email layout that you've created instead of inside your typical web application layout (e.g. `application.html.erb`).

And that's pretty much it.  Now I can visit http://example.com/admin/mailer/preview_welcome to preview change to my welcome email template.

Comment: This was in fact exactly the approach I had taken and just coded as I started to read your answer - thank you :)

Comment: Now that's a tasty recipe! Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Freaking brilliant. Voted up.

Comment: Also, if you want to test different formats, its the normal respond_with scenario:

  class MailerController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :text

    def preview_order_submitted
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
      respond_with(@order, :file => 'customer_mailer/order_submitted')  
    end
  end

Comment: The route should be `get 'mailer...` now instead of `match`.

Comment: works better than this *wtf* rails4.1 integration of the mail_view gem

Answer (score 18):

37Signals also has their own mail testing gem called [mail_view](https://github.com/37signals/mail_view). It's pretty fantastic.

Comment: No problem. What way did you end up using?

Comment: Bac when I posted this I solved the problem with a custom controller I wrote myself but am going to hit it again soon so will be experimenting with this

Comment: This functionality is now a part of Rails (as of 2023-10-27)

Answer (score 16):

The easiest setup I've seen is [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/). Setup took 2 minutes, and it works for new mailers out of the box.

Comment: This indeed is great.  Setup is very fast and works for all mailers!  Great tip!

Answer (score 11):

I use [email_preview](https://github.com/wireframe/email_preview). Give it a try.

Answer (score 11):

Easiest solution in rails 5, rails 6, and rails 7: just remember one url:

[http://localhost:3000/**rails/mailers**](http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers)

Comment: This also works under Rails 5. This method uses ActionMailer::Preview. More information is available in Rails Guides : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised no one's mentioned [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener).  It's a gem that will render and open emails as a browser page whenever an email is delivered in dev.

Comment: letter_opener is a cool gem and it's a must have.
But sometimes the mail start from special events that you want to avoid playing to check purely the html/css of the mail.

Answer (score 7):

I recently wrote a gem named [Maily](https://github.com/markets/maily) to preview, edit (template file) and deliver the application emails via a browser. It also provides a friendly way to hook data, a flexible authorization system and a minimalist UI.

[image]

I have planned to add new features in the near future, like:

- Multiple hooks per email
- Parametrize emails via UI (arguments of mailer method)
- Play with translations keys (list, highlight, ...)

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 6):

`rails` generates a mail preview if you use `rails g mailer CustomMailer`.
You will get a file `CustomMailerPreview` inside `spec/mailers/previews` folder.

Here you can write your method that will call the mailer and it'll generate a preview.

For ex -

```
class CustomMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def contact_us_mail_preview
    CustomMailer.my_mail(user: User.first)
  end
end
```

Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/custom_mailer

Comment: For my app with rspec I added  

`config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailers/previews"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Rails Email Preview](https://github.com/glebm/rails_email_preview)

[image: rails-email-preview screenshot]

[REP](https://github.com/glebm/rails_email_preview) is a rails engine to preview and test send emails, with I18n support, easy premailer integration, and optional CMS editing with [comfortable_mexican_sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa).

Comment: Are there any samples on how to actually do the integration betwen REP and CMS?

Comment: I don't know of any demo applications, but there is a comprehensive [article in the wiki](https://github.com/glebm/rails_email_preview/wiki/Edit-Emails-with-Comfortable-Mexican-Sofa)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to preview it directly out of the Mailer.
But as you wrote, you can write a controller, which looks something like this.

```
class EmailPreviewsControllers < ActionController::Base
  def show
    render "#{params[:mailer]}_mailer/#{params[:method]}"
  end
end
```

But I think, that's not the best way to test emails, if they look correctly.

Comment: `render "#{params[:mailer]}_mailer/#{params[:method]}", :layout => 'mailer'` will embed the body of the email inside the HTML email layout you have created for your app.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm not wanting to double-check browser compatibility, I would treat that separately, I just simply want to spit the thing out quickly and see how it looks - I think your approach works well for that

Answer (score 3):

Rails Email Preview helps us to quickly view the email in web browser in development mode.

1. Add `“gem ‘rails_email_preview’, ‘~> 0.2.29’ “` to gem file and bundle install.
2. Run `“rails g rails_email_preview:install”` this creates initializer in config folder and add routes.
3. Run `“rails g rails_email_preview:update_previews”` this crates mailer_previews folder in app directory.

Generator will add a stub to each of your emails, then u populate the stub with mock data.

Ex:

```rb
class UserMailerPreview
  def invitation
    UserMailer.invitation mock_user(‘Alice’), mock_user(‘Bob’)
  end
  def welcome
    UserMailer.welcome mock_user
  end
  private
  def mock_user(name = ‘Bill Gates’)
    fake_id User.new(name: name, email: “user#{rand 100}@test.com”)
  end
  def fake_id(obj)
    obj.define_singleton_method(:id) { 123 + rand(100) }
    obj
  end
end
```

4. Parameters in search query will be available as an instance variable to preview class. Ex: if we have a URL like
   `“/emails/user_mailer_preview-welcome?user_id=1”` `@user_id` is defined in welcome method of `UserMailerPreview` it helps us to send mail to specific user.

```rb
class UserMailerPreview
  def welcome
    user = @user_id ? User.find(@user_id) : mock_user
    UserMailer.welcome(user)
  end
end
```

5. To access REP url’s like this

```rb
rails_email_preview.rep_root_url
rails_email_preview.rep_emails_url
rails_email_preview.rep_email_url(‘user_mailer-welcome’)
```

6. We can send emails via REP, this will use environment mailer settings. Uncomment this line in the initializer to disable sending mail in test environment.

`config.enable_send_email = false`

Source : [RailsCarma Blog : Previewing Emails in Rails Applications With the Mail_View Gem](http://www.railscarma.com/blog/technical-articles/previewing-emails-in-rails-applications-with-the-mail_view-gem/)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [mails_viewer](https://github.com/pragmaticly/mails_viewer) gem. This gem is quite useful as it save the HTML template into tmp folder.