# How to see e-mail views in browser using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am working on e-mails for my rails app.  Right now the only way I know to view the e-mail is to send it to myself.  How do I get "daily_summary.html.haml", which is in the "notifications" folder under the "views" folder, to render in the browser?  I was thinking I should just add the route:

```
match 'notifications' => 'notifications/daily_summary'
```

But then I don't know how to handle the controller/action side of things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I preview emails in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165064/how-do-i-preview-emails-in-rails)

Comment: I use MailCatcher - https://mailcatcher.me/ - run it, open up a new browswer tab - and you will see emails delivered there.

Answer (score 14):

Since Rails 4.1, e-mail preview is native.
All you need to do is create a class in this directory:

```
test/mailers/previews/
```

The class must extend `ActionMailer::Preview`

```
class WeeklyReportPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    def weekly_report
        WeeklyReport.weekly_report(User.first)
    end
end
```

Write methods that return `Mail::Message` objects. They are accessible in the development environment using this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/[preview_class_name]/[method_name]
```

In my case:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/weekly_report/weekly_report
```

More info can be found in the [ActionMailer API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Previewing+emails)

Comment: For anyone ending up here - i got side tracked by the fact that many reference creating previews in test/mailers etc. however if you have tests in spec its actually spec/mailers ... otherwise works a treat!

Answer (score 10):

There's a gem called Letter Opener that sounds like it'll do exactly what you're looking for. It previews email messages in the browser rather than sending them. I haven't used it myself. If it works I'd love to hear about it, though!

https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

There's another one called Mail Viewer but it hasn't been actively developed in quite some time. Probably better to steer clear:

https://github.com/37signals/mail_view

Comment: Letter Opener seems to be working.  Only thing is that it is opening the 'plain.html' versions of the e-mail instead of the 'rich.html' versions (the plain seems to correspond to the text version of my email and the rich to the html version).  Any idea how I could change this?

Comment: It looks like, within the `deliver` block you can specify both a `text_part` block and an `html_part` block. And you have to set `content_type` to `'text/html'` in the html_part block. See if that works.

Comment: I'm a little ignorant here. . where do you see these blocks and where can I set the content_type?

Comment: Yeah, the docs are a bit sparse. Take a look at the rspec tests in the github repo: https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/blob/master/spec/letter_opener/delivery_method_spec.rb. The second test has an example of what you're trying to do, I think.

Comment: I am using letter opener to check the emails locally. However, I can only check the emails sent to the user, I cannot see the cc users email copy. Any Idea what might be the reason?

Comment: @Murthy, If I understand correctly, you want to verify that the cc'ed users also receive the message? That's outside the scope of Letter Opener, in my opinion. You should write a test for that instead.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. I was expecting it to open more windows locally showing the emails for all the cc'ed users. Thanks Tom. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [actionmailer_extensions](https://github.com/originalpete/actionmailer_extensions). It makes ActionMailer write outgoing emails to the disk as .eml files. This might be enough for your purposes (just set up a script to watch the output directory for new files and open them in your preferred email client), or you could fork the gem and modify it directly (its source is dead simple) to write .html files and open them in your browser instead.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3 there is now a gem, `mail_view`, which was include in Rails 4.1. Here is a link to [set-up](https://github.com/basecamp/mail_view). It is quite easy.

1.) Add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'mail_view', :git => https://github.com/basecamp/mail_view.git'
# or
gem "mail_view", "~> 2.0.4"
```

2.) in routes.rb:

```
 # config/routes.rb
 if Rails.env.development?
    mount MailPreview => 'mail_view'
 end
```

3.) Create a MailPreview model:

```
 # app/mailers/mail_preview.rb or lib/mail_preview.rb
class MailPreview < MailView
...
 def forgot_password
   user = Struct.new(:email, :name).new('name@example.com', 'Jill Smith')
   mail = UserMailer.forgot_password(user)
 end
end
```

In this model you can name the methods whatever you want, but it makes sense that they correspond to UserMailer methods.

4.) To view go to `/mail_view` for a list of all methods in MailPreview. Click on one to see the HTML preview right there in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is already contained in @Daniel Cukier's answer, but the super quick answer is just remember this one route (`/rails/mailers`), i.e.:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers
```

This gives access to an index of all the mailers